# WSO2 API manager(1.9) Publisher APIs - Can not update query parameter using "updateApi" action

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

WSO2 API manager(1.9) Publisher APIs - Can not update query parameter using "[Update Api](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM190/Publisher+APIs#PublisherAPIs-UpdateAPI)" action.

I had created one API using WSO2 API manager(1.9) Publisher APIs "[Add API](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM190/Publisher+APIs#PublisherAPIs-AddAPI)" by specifying swagger in the request. It has lots for header and query parameters for each uritemplate.

When I tried to update the same API using [Publisher APIs](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM190/Publisher+APIs), I can not find any option to specify the parameters(header/query). This "[Update Api](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM190/Publisher+APIs#PublisherAPIs-UpdateAPI)" action is allowing to add swagger definition.

Can anyone please help me here?

Is there a way to specify parameters(header/query) for each URITemplate while updating the API using [Publisher APIs](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM190/Publisher+APIs)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can you the following curl commands to add and update APIs with query parameters.

ADD API

> curl -X POST -b cookies
>   http://localhost:9763/publisher/site/blocks/item-add/ajax/add.jag -d
>   "action=addAPI&name=PhoneVerification&context=/phoneverify&version=1.0.0&visibility=public&thumbUrl=&description=Verify
>   a phone
>   number&tags=phone,mobile,multimedia&endpointType=nonsecured&tiersCollection=Gold,Bronze&http_checked=http&https_checked=https&default_version_checked=default_version&bizOwner=xx&bizOwnerMail=xx@ee.com&techOwner=xx&techOwnerMail=ggg@ww.com"
>   -d 'endpoint_config={"production_endpoints":{"url":"http://ws.cdyne.com/phoneverify/phoneverify.asmx","config":null},"endpoint_type":"http"}'
>   -d 'swagger={"paths" : {"/CheckPhoneNumber" : {"post" : {"x-auth-type" : "Application%20%26%20Application%20User", "x-scope" : "read_number",
>   "x-throttling-tier" : "Unlimited", "responses" : {"200" : {}}}, "get"
>   : {"x-auth-type" : "Application%20%26%20Application%20User",
>   "x-throttling-tier" : "Unlimited", "responses" : {"200" : {}},
>   "parameters" : [{"name" : "PhoneNumber", "paramType" : "query",
>   "required" : false, "type" : "string", "description" : "Phone Number",
>   "in" : "query"}, {"name" : "LicenseKey", "paramType" : "query",
>   "required" : false, "type" : "string", "description" : "License Key",
>   "in" : "query"}]}}, "/" : {"put" : {"responses" : {"200" : {}}}, "get"
>   : {"responses" : {"200" : {}}}}}, "swagger" : "2.0",
>   "securityDefinitions" : {"apim" : {"x-wso2-scopes" : [{"description" :
>   "", "name" : "read_number", "roles" : "admin", "key" :
>   "read_number"}]}}, "info" : {"title" : "PhoneVerification", "version"
>   : "1.0.0"}}'

`

UPDATE API

> curl -X POST -b cookies
>   http://localhost:9763/publisher/site/blocks/item-add/ajax/add.jag -d
>   "action=updateAPI&name=PhoneVerification&context=/phoneverify&version=1.0.0&visibility=public&thumbUrl=&description=Verify
>   a phone
>   number&tags=phone,mobile,multimedia&endpointType=nonsecured&tiersCollection=Gold,Bronze&http_checked=http&https_checked=https&default_version_checked=default_version&bizOwner=xx&bizOwnerMail=xx@ee.com&techOwner=xx&techOwnerMail=ggg@ww.com"
>   -d 'endpoint_config={"production_endpoints":{"url":"http://ws.cdyne.com/phoneverify/phoneverify.asmx","config":null},"endpoint_type":"http"}'
>   -d 'swagger={"paths" : {"/CheckPhoneNumber" : {"post" : {"x-auth-type" : "Application%20%26%20Application%20User", "x-scope" : "read_number",
>   "x-throttling-tier" : "Unlimited", "responses" : {"200" : {}}}, "get"
>   : {"x-auth-type" : "Application%20%26%20Application%20User",
>   "x-throttling-tier" : "Unlimited", "responses" : {"200" : {}},
>   "parameters" : [{"name" : "PhoneNumberCHANGED", "paramType" : "query",
>   "required" : false, "type" : "string", "description" : "Phone Number",
>   "in" : "query"}, {"name" : "LicenseKeyCHANGED", "paramType" : "query",
>   "required" : false, "type" : "string", "description" : "License Key",
>   "in" : "query"}]}}, "/" : {"put" : {"responses" : {"200" : {}}}, "get"
>   : {"responses" : {"200" : {}}}}}, "swagger" : "2.0",
>   "securityDefinitions" : {"apim" : {"x-wso2-scopes" : [{"description" :
>   "", "name" : "read_number", "roles" : "admin", "key" :
>   "read_number"}]}}, "info" : {"title" : "PhoneVerification", "version"
>   : "1.0.0"}}'